# Procedural Ivy with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I know there's the [ivy gen](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_curve/ivy_gen.html) addon for blender, but I'm wondering if anyone has an approach to recreating such an effect with geometry nodes?

The curves of the ivy need to stick to the surface of the mesh.

Comment: Could you please tell us more about your project and your problem? Screenshots or blend file? The way this question is currently formulated, it can be answered with yes and with no. It depends very much on your requirements, and maybe the answer goes beyond the usual scope here... Thank you!